# fast scroll custom thumb

Tags: android, scroll, performance

how can i set custom thumb for fast scroll in listview.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can set that into the style.xml

```
<style name="Theme_app" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:fastScrollThumbDrawable">@drawable/fastscroll_thumb_holo</item>

 </style>
```

than create an xml in Drawable for the image

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/fastscroll_thumb_pressed_holo" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/fastscroll_thumb_default_holo" />
</selector>
```

Answer (score 5):

Setting the Drawable from styles is the way to go. However, if you want to do this programmatically here are two methods that should be useful:

```
/**
 * Set a ListView or GridView fast scroll thumb image.
 * 
 * @param listView The {@link android.widget.ListView} or {@link android.widget.GridView}
 * @param thumb The fast-scroll drawable
 * @return {@code true} if successfully set.
 */
public static boolean setFastScrollThumbImage(AbsListView listView, Drawable thumb) {
    try {
        Field f;
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            f = AbsListView.class.getDeclaredField("mFastScroll");
        } else {
            f = AbsListView.class.getDeclaredField("mFastScroller");
        }
        f.setAccessible(true);
        Object o = f.get(listView);
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            f = f.getType().getDeclaredField("mThumbImage");
            f.setAccessible(true);
            ImageView iv = (ImageView) f.get(o);
            iv.setImageDrawable(thumb);
        } else {
            f = f.getType().getDeclaredField("mThumbDrawable");
            f.setAccessible(true);
            Drawable drawable = (Drawable) f.get(o);
            drawable = thumb;
            f.set(o, drawable);
        }
        return true;
    } catch (Exception ignored) {
    }
    return false;
}

/**
 * Set a ListView or GridView fast scroll thumb color.
 * 
 * @param listView The {@link android.widget.ListView} or {@link android.widget.GridView}
 * @param color The color for the fast-scroll thumb
 * @return {@code true} if successfully set.
 */
public static boolean setFastScrollThumbColor(AbsListView listView, int color) {
    try {
        Field f;
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            f = AbsListView.class.getDeclaredField("mFastScroll");
        } else {
            f = AbsListView.class.getDeclaredField("mFastScroller");
        }
        f.setAccessible(true);
        Object o = f.get(listView);
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            f = f.getType().getDeclaredField("mThumbImage");
            f.setAccessible(true);
            ImageView iv = (ImageView) f.get(o);
            iv.setColorFilter(color, android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
        } else {
            f = f.getType().getDeclaredField("mThumbDrawable");
            f.setAccessible(true);
            final Drawable drawable = (Drawable) f.get(o);
            drawable.setColorFilter(color, android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
        }
        return true;
    } catch (Exception ignored) {
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

hard code for android kitkat (field "mThumbDrawable" in FastScroller (android kitkat) is not exist)

```
try {
            java.lang.reflect.Field f = AbsListView.class.getDeclaredField("mFastScroller");
            f.setAccessible(true);
            Object o = f.get(root.findViewById(R.id.beam_contact_listview));
            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
                f = f.getType().getDeclaredField("mThumbImage");
            } else {
                f = f.getType().getDeclaredField("mThumbDrawable");
            }
            f.setAccessible(true);
            Drawable drawable = (Drawable) f.get(o);
            drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.sv_fastscroll);
            f.set(o, drawable);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: mThumbImage is not a Drawable on KitKat+, it is an ImageButton.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a look at the source code for Android 2.2r1 (revision 1), there is a class called `android.widget.FastScroller`, which has the method `useThumbDrawable()`.

I just [downloaded the source from a blog called MobileBytes](http://mobilebytes.wordpress.com/2010/06/30/classes-source-for-eclipse/) which contains it, maybe you could import that into your project and implement it? (or upgrade your API to 2.2 r1)

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the `android:fastScrollThumbDrawable` but I not know why it isn't working, so searching on web i found [here](http://www.cnblogs.com/zhuqiang/archive/2013/01/22/2871318.html) a hard code solution, I not know if it works on old API but in my case was solved the problem. Note I'm using API 18 like target and a device with API 17 to test.

the code:

```
try {
    Field f = AbsListView.class.getDeclaredField("mFastScroller");
    f.setAccessible(true);
    Object o = f.get(<<your listView here>>);
    f = f.getType().getDeclaredField("mThumbDrawable");
    f.setAccessible(true);
    Drawable drawable = (Drawable) f.get(o);
    drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.<<your thumb drawable here can be a selector>>);
    f.set(o, drawable);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```